# Reactjs create a border, while plain html doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

My problem is, when i use this code on the js React file, i get basically two sidebars, and no matter what i do, i can't figure out how to remove them, in the css there's no border/padding on the sides.

```
class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="container-fluid">

        <div className="container-fluid home-div">
         <img className="profile-pic" src="https://www.ladyblitz.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/fbShared-e1442238915211.jpg"/>
          <h1 className="title">Title</h1>
          <h1 className="title-js">subtitle</h1>
        </div>

        <div className="container-fluid biography-div">
          <h1 className="biography-title">-- title thing --</h1>
          <p className="biography-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

But if i take the html and write it in the html file, everything works perfectly, i can use the full width of the page, no sidebars, can anyone explain me why?

Comment: If you open up the `public` folder you will see that the component with id `root` is a `<div>`. Your React after being compiled into javascript file will use that `<div>` as starting point to add/remove component. That `div` may be your source of bug.

Comment: ok i figured it out, turns out it was a bug in the libraries i was using for the root div classes